# Black screen after kernel update to 3.13.0-103-generic on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, updates

I just made a kernel update in my Ubuntu 14.04 from kernel version 3.13.0-101-generic to 3.13.0-103-generic. The boot logo of Ubuntu is shown and then only black screen is displayed. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution... 
First I noticed that Ubuntu was loading fine in recovery mode and it was giving black screen in normal boot mode.

So i edited grub file with command

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

For line

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

changed it to
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"

I saved it and run the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

And restarted, it works fine.

Ubuntu boots as expected but there's still a problem. I had saved some script than run on startup and set my screen brightness to some lower value, now I lost it. For now, I am ok with the solution I got.